# Using Flash Drive to Give Extra Memory to Computer?

Tags: windows-8, usb-flash-drive, gateway

I am running on a bad 4g Windows-8 Gateway laptop. I have a lot of files and coding scripts. This is causing my memory to drain. I was wondering if I could clean a flash drive (Which I know how to do) and convert it to extra memory on my computer?

Comment: Differentiate between memory and filespace;  if you have "lots of files", that's not using memory, it's using filespace (i.e. what is stored on a disk drive).  You can use a USB drive for additional drive space, but it's an expensive and slow solution.  And if you really mean -memory- then, no, you can't use a storage drive instead of buying more memory.  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Hardware - see RAM vs Storage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a storage disk (such as a USB drive) as RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/373484/is-it-possible-to-use-a-storage-disk-such-as-a-usb-drive-as-ram), [How to use a pendrive as RAM?](http://superuser.com/questions/224456/how-to-use-a-pendrive-as-ram?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it won't be "Physical Memory," it is possible to use a USB as "Virtual Memory" on your computer or laptop using [ReadyBoost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readyboost).

Readyboost is a feature available on many Windows versions (including Windows 8), that allows your computer or laptop to use some, or all of your flash drive's storage space as "Virtual Memory," to increase overall performance.

If you are looking for a tutorial, [Vipansh](http://www.youtube.com/user/vipansh) does an excellent job at explaining how to set up ReadyBoost on Windows 8 [HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mlyda8Lk0Ps).